# AWS Lambda python library function error

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql

I'm trying to connect to AWS RDS using AWS Lambda. I installed PyMySQL to the directory and built the package with the code below and the libraries

```
import sys
import pymysql

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    string=""
    try:
            connection = pymysql.connect(host='',
                                            user='',
                                            password='',
                                            db='',
                                            charset='',
                                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            cur = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            cur.execute("select * from table")
            for row in cur:
                    print(row['col'])
                    string+=row['col']
    except Exception as e:
            print("MySQL error: %s" % (e.args[0]))

    return string

print(lambda_handler("",""))
```

In my machine, the code above works, but in AWS, it displays

> MySQL error: module 'pymysql' has no attribute 'connect'

I checked that pymysql is only available in the directory that has the code, so I don't know why I'm not able to use the connect method.
Both Python versions are the same.

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='',
AttributeError: module 'pymysql' has no attribute 'connect'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: @roganjosh Done

Comment: :( I was hoping it might have shed a bit more light on the issue but I don't take anything from that

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah, when you asked me that I had a "OF COURSE" moment, but got disappointed as well...

Comment: What do you get from `print(dir(pymysql))`? My suspicion is that you have named another script `pymysql.py` somewhere that's on the PATH. Do you recognise anything in `dir` that is of your creation?

Comment: I do not, but I'm gonna check that out.

Comment: Well, guess what?
`['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`. I don't know, but I have no other script but lambda.py...

Comment: How did you package and upload the Lambda function to AWS?

Comment: I installed the library to the directory with `pip install --target=. PyMySQL` and then `zip package.zip *`. I then uploaded package.zip to AWS.

Comment: I would suspect there is a problem with the way you created the package/zipped it. Are you familiar with SAM?

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: My environment is an AWS Lambda function. I have in the directory pymysql and the function itself, lambda.py

Answer (score 1):

Try `zip -r package.zip *`

I suspect you are zipping only the top level of the pymysql module, not the contents of its subdirectories

The AWS documentation for uploading to lambda is pretty poor.

Comment: The subdirectories and files are present. I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a directory in your local machine eg: "package-dir"
2. Now install pymlsql to your created directory path "pip install pymlsql -t path/to/package-dir"
3. Paste you python script to the same dirctory
4. Select all the items inside the directory and create a zip file. Do not zip the directory itself this is very important
5. Upload the zip file in lambda and it should work
6. Also see that the handler name is "python_script_name.lambda_handler".
   Eg: if your script file name is "lambda_function.py" then your handler should be "lambda_function.lambda_handler"